# Python: Pass 1 argument to a 2d array of functions and get results in 2d array of same size

Tags: python, arrays, lambda

if i define a 2d array of lambda functions like:

```
N_gsi = [ [lambda gsi:1/4*(1+gsi[1]),     lambda gsi:1/4*(1+gsi[0])],
          [lambda gsi:-1/4*(1+gsi[1]),    lambda gsi:1/4*(1-gsi[0])],     
          [lambda gsi:-1/4*(1-gsi[1]),    lambda gsi:-1/4*(1-gsi[0])],    
          [lambda gsi:1/4*(1-gsi[1]),     lambda gsi:-1/4*(1+gsi[0])]]
```

is it then possible to get the result for each function (using the same argument gsi of course) into a array of the same size in an elegant way? (no loop)

something like:

```
resultArray = N_gsi(myArgumentGsi)
```

Comment: `1/4` gives `0` in Python 2 by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you need do a little change.

```
N_gsi = lambda gsi: [ [1/4*(1+gsi[1]), 1/4*(1+gsi[0])], [-1/4*(1+gsi[1]), 1/4*(1-gsi[0])], [-1/4*(1-gsi[1]), -1/4*(1-gsi[0])], [1/4*(1-gsi[1]), -1/4*(1+gsi[0])]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This little function should do the trick for collections with arbitrary nesting depth. I'm not sure if you would count recursion as a loop here.

```
def apply(fs, arg):
    if callable(fs):
        return fs(arg)
    else:
        return list(map(lambda f: apply(f, arg), fs))
```

With this you could then write `lambda gsi: apply(N_gsi, gsi)` for your particular use case.